# Submit Input and Label do not align inside form

Tags: css

[image: Screenshot-at-2019-10-22-15-40-20.png]

As you can see from the picture, the two button looking things "Browse Files" and "Upload" are misaligned.

The issue is that the submit input "Upload" has 1 pixel between it's top border and the `<form>`'s top border. So in between them there is a 1px empty space. "Browse files" does not have this empty space between itself and the top border of the `<form>`.

```css
.center_box {
    width: 600px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 40px auto;
    text-align: left;
}

.upload_firmware_container {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.upload_firmware_container form {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.file_input_label {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #e11422;
    border:none;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin-right:20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#files {
    display: none;
}

input[type="submit" i] {
    padding: 0;
}

.upload_button {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #1489e1;
    border:none;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.upload_button:hover, .upload_button:focus {
    background-color: #0e5e9b;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="center_box">
      <div class = "upload_firmware_container">
         <form method = "POST" action="/doUpload"     enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label class="file_input_label" for="files">Browse     files</label>
            <input id="files" type="file" name="data"/>
            <input class="upload_button" type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" title = "Upload Files">
         </form>
         <form method="POST">
            <input class = "restart_button" type="submit" name="restart_device" value="Restart Device">
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
```

It is driving me crazy. I have no idea how to fix this.

I have tried eliminating the padding from the inputs but it did not work:

```
input[type="submit" i] {
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have been playing with Chrome's tools for the past hour and I can't identify the issue. Nothing I change or do fix that stray pixel.

Comment: with the code you shared we cannot reproduce the problem. Even after i use `display:none` on the `input[type='file']` which i think you forgot to put in your code. So, can you reproduce your problem in this snippet ?

Comment: @MihaiT Done ! I thought that adding a lot of code is against SO politics...

Comment: That snippet still doesn’t seem to reproduce the problem though, at least in Chrome I can’t spot anything like the problem you are describing.

Comment: @04FS That's strange. I'm also using Chrome and I can see the misalignment in the snippet.. We are talking about 1px in difference. It won't work if you zoom in. Once you zoom in, the Submit moves.

Comment: No zoom, no difference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMNm2.png I painted in the green rectangle, it has 1px margin to the buttons, they align on the same horizontal line without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
input[type="submit" i] {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This actually works. Only `vertical-align: top;` is needed. `padding` does nothing. How can I specify this rule to only this input `<input class="upload_button" type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" title = "Upload Files">` ?

Comment: @MihaiT In my case: `.upload_firmware_container input{}` . Thanks !

Comment: `.upload_firmware_container input.upload_button{}` by this because you have other input also which have different class name `Restart Device` so if you use above mention rule it will only target` Upload Files` input .